# android proguard can't find referenced class with google-gson

Tags: android, gson, proguard

I get these warnings when I run progard despite of using the sample proguard file from the google-gson project.

```
    [2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-09 12:06:23 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
```

Here is the sample proguard file I have put in my proguard-project.txt file

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt 
-printseeds seeds.txt 
-printusage unused.txt 
-printmapping mapping.txt 
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Comment: try uncommenting line: #-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; } (delete the'#' sign)